# How do I use a checkbox to disable a form 'month' input using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to be able to enable the checkbox 'present' to disable the input 'dateend'. Here's what I've tried to do, where am I going wrong?

```
        <input type="month" name="dateend" class="form-control" required>
        <input type="checkbox" id="present" onchange="present()">
        <script>
            function present() {
                document.getElementsByName("dateend").disabled = true;
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("dateend")` is a NodeList collection...not a single element

Comment: Explanation given by @charlietfl. Solution: replace document.getElementsByName("dateend").disabled = true; with document.querySelector("input[name='dateend']").disabled = true and it should work

Comment: @charlietfl thanks. I've switched the dateend to have 'id="dateend"' rather than a name and tried using 'document.getElementById()' in my javascript with no change in result - any ideas?

Comment: @Will Thanks Will I've tried this but no luck. I've tried various different ways of doing this without success

Comment: Might need to remove `required` also since required and disabled have conflicting purposes

Comment: Seems to be working here: https://jsfiddle.net/9skwhc0r/ What do you get?

Comment: @Will I'm getting this output from the console: 'Uncaught TypeError: present is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange (employment:109)
onchange @ employment:109'

Comment: You're getting that in jsfiddle?

Comment: @Will No from the JavaScript console on my own page - jsfiddle works fine for me too. I'm quite new to JavaScript, and I'm not sure if I need to be including additional source files for this to work.

Comment: It's just simple basic JS, no library needed. Looks like your function has not been set. Check for typos and make sure your script is present on your page.

Comment: @Will Simple resolve - the checkbox id  is 'present' as is my functions name. When I changed my function name, it worked. In future I'll make sure to keep a distinction between id's and function names. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. You're welcome.